# Load customized metrics failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a customized metrics called `f1_metric`,

and I'm trying to load my model with this customized metrics with following code

```py
def f1_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_val = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon())
    return f1_val


metric_dict = {
    'f1_metric':f1_metric
}

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(models_save,custom_objects = metric_dict)
```

but I'm still running into the situation where error shows `ValueError: Unknown metric function:f1_metric`

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
x = f1_metric
metric_dict = {'x':f1_metric}
```

> If that does not work, try updating Keras and TensorFlow on your
>   device and run the code again.

If that fails too, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706192/10399281

Comment: I actually found the [reason](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32348), it's an answer for customized loss function, but same method apply to metrics

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the load_model() while loading and compiling the model at one go. btw did it work?