# Unknown metric error when loading keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I have trained my regression model with no issues. Trains and tests perfectly.
I used the `model.save(model_filename)` to save it.
When I try to load back the model using `model = load_model(model_filename)` I get the following error.

> ValueError: Unknown metric function: {'class_name':
> 'RootMeanSquaredError', 'config': {'name': 'root_mean_squared_error',
> 'dtype': 'float32'}}

Any ideas what is going on?

Here is my model definition:

```
def RegressionCNN2(input_shape,learning_rate):
    model = Sequential()
    #model.add(keras.Input(shape = input_shape))
    #model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=366))
    #model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), init='uniform'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))

    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
                      optimizer=opt,
                      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()] 
                     )
    return model
```

Code for training:

```
# Create model
    model = RegressionCNN2((netH,netW,3),learning_rate)
    
    print(train_ims.shape,train_labels.shape)
    # Train model
    
    model.fit(train_ims, train_labels,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epochs,
              verbose=2,
              validation_data=(valid_ims, valid_labels),
              shuffle = True,
              use_multiprocessing = True,
              callbacks=my_callbacks)
```

Thanks in advance!

**----Update-----**

I saved the weights and and the architecture instead of using model.save() and I recompiled the model after loading and works fine. If you have any alternatives would love to hear them. Here is my solution:

```
json_file = open('net_name.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights('net_name.h5')
print("Loaded model from disk")
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                      optimizer=opt,
                      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()] 
                     )
```

**----Update2----**

It was a version control issue.
Using `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_name)` solved it.
However in general storing the weights and the architecture and just recompiling seems a more robust approach as it worked across versions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700351/valueerror-unknown-metric-function-when-using-custom-metric-in-keras does this help?

Comment: I did check that but in my case I haven't defined any custom metrics... I just use keras default metrics... That's why I am confused